# Examples of Maass forms with eigenvalue 1/4

Tags: reference-request, modular-forms

For what I have heard, Maass forms of (Laplacian) eigenvalue $1/4$ on modular surfaces are somewhat special. But I don't know where to look for explicit examples. (In fact, one form came here on MO [Does anyone want a pretty Maass form?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22908/does-anyone-want-a-pretty-maass-form), but I am not sure I can figure out what it is from the description.)
So, can anyone help me with references?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One place you can look is the paper by [Booker and Strombergsson](http://www2.math.uu.se/~astrombe/papers/stfz14march06.pdf) which appeared in Crelle.  Their aim is to verify the Selberg eigenvalue conjecture in a number of cases, and when there are Maass forms of eigenvalue $1/4$ these must be accounted for by finding corresponding Galois representations.  See Section 5 of the paper for some explicit examples; of course there is a lot of other work on this, but the paper will give you more references.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, this is good reference. It would be nice though if someone published coefficients of some form.

Comment: I mean, I would like coefficients and can, if necessary, compute them. But who isn't lazy, and busy?